# Webcam issues on Lenovo Ideapad Y510 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, skype, lenovo, webcam, ideapad

Skype an Google Hangouts seem to be unable to use my build-in webcam on IdeaPad Y510.

In Skype it just does not show me the option to start video conversation. But when I am going to Skype -> Options -> Video Devices, it *does* recognize the webcam:

> `Lenovo EasyCamera (/dev/video0)`

I am able to see myself there.
Needless to say the checkbox `Enable Skype Video` is checked.

In Google Hangouts my feed from webcam is shows black screen. (in the settings it is also shows correct device)

Cheese seems to be working.

I converted from Windows to Ubuntu just recently so please excuse if I am missing some 'obvious' checks or steps *before* asking this question.
I did lots of googling on this issue but could not find any useful solution.

**UPDATE**: After installing V4L2 drivers and the control panel the issue is gone for the Google Hangouts. But not for Skype...

Comment: You need to install the `v4l2` packages to use videos in other applications. Follow this article to install `v4l2`: http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/v4l2/

Comment: @user308564 : I have followed instructions on the article provided but not all packages were found. I have installed Video4Linux CP - it works and shows the feed from webcam. but does not solve the issue with skype. BTW it fixed Google hangout issue

Answer (score 2):

First install the Webcam drivers and needed packages:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` libsbigudrv2 libsbigudrv0
```

Then for use those videos for other applications, install `v4l2`:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2ucp v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-source v4l2loopback-utils gem-plugin-v4l2 libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2 libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2 qv4l2 v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-source v4l2loopback-utils v4l2ucp dvswitch dov4l dv4l gambas2-gb-v4l gambas3-gb-v4l gem-plugin-dv4l gem-plugin-v4l2 libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2 libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2 libv4l-ruby1.8 libv4lconvert0 libvideo-capture-v4l-perl qv4l2 v4l-conf v4l-utils
```

Comment: I am getting following when trying to install v4l2:

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2'
E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2'
E: Unable to locate package gambas2-gb-v4l
E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l'
E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.10.10-plugins-v4l2'

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l'
E: Unable to locate package libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpt-1.11.2-plugins-v4l2'
E: Unable to locate package libv4l-ruby1.8
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libv4l-ruby1.8'

Comment: its ok. those packages are not in 14.04. that list made for 13.04. rdemove them and install the rest.

Answer (score 2):

For webcam drivers

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` libsbigudrv2 libsbigudrv0
```

to install `v4l2`( Video4Linux2) in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2ucp v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-source v4l2loopback-utils gem-plugin-v4l2 qv4l2 v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-source v4l2loopback-utils v4l2ucp dvswitch dov4l dv4l gambas3-gb-v4l gem-plugin-dv4l gem-plugin-v4l2 libv4lconvert0 libvideo-capture-v4l-perl qv4l2 v4l-conf v4l-utils
```

Comment: This helped to me.

Comment: All these packages come back as "unable to locate" on my computer, any advise?